# How can I push a one remote branch so it catches up with my other remote branch

Tags: git

[git visual of the branches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgmiw.png)

I have 2 remote branches, a github one and a heroku one. I want to push the heroku branch so that it is the same as the github one. How do I do this?

Comment: Where do you want to push?

Comment: @rasengan__ I want to make the master of the heroku repo and the github repo the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In command-line (not GitKraken), assuming that:

- `git remote -v` gives you two remote URLS: one for GitHub (`origin`) and one for heroku (`heroku`)
- you don't have current work in progress (`git status` is clear)

Then:

```
git switch master
# or git checkout, if Git lower than 2.23

git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master
git push --force heroku master
```